# How to translate DLL Function Call / DllImport from vb6 to C# .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, dllimport

The code in VB6 works perfectly fine, I believe the dll is coded in assmebly for speed, I'm trying to port calling it in C# or VB.NET whichever I don't mind.. I tried many different tricks nothing works, It should be called similar to how RltMoveMemory (CopyMemory) is called with a Array address passed by offset.

The VB6 code looks like this

```
Public Type REGTYPE
  REG_Kind As Byte  ' ;1=8 bits \ 2=16 bits \ 3=32 bits \ 4=MMX \ 5=XMM \ 6=Float stack \ 7=Segment \ 8=Debug \ 9=Control \ 10=Test
  REG_Ptr_Kind As Byte  ' ;1=Byte PTR \ 2=Word PTR \ 3=Dword PTR \ 4=Qword PTR \ 5=mmword ptr \ 6=xmmword ptr \ 7=FWord PTR \ 8=tbyte ptr \ 9=null ptr (LEA)
  REG_Type As Byte '  ;0-7= direct register index \ 16 register=byte && 7 \ 32 register=(byte && 63)/8 \ 64=[32/16 address only] \ 128=[using x86 relatives]
  REG_BaseAsReg As Byte ' ? ;1=Register only (BASE exposed)!
End Type

Public Type REGSTRUCT
 SEG_TYPE As Long
 Base As Long
 INDEX As Long
 SCALE As Long
 DISPLACEMENTS As Long
 DISPLACEMENT_TYPE As Long
 REG_Kind As REGTYPE
 PTR_TYPE As Long
End Type

Public Type IMMSTRUCT
 VALUE_LO As Long
 VALUE_HI As Long
 VALUE_TYPE As Long '     1=Byte \ 2=Word \ 4=Dword \ 8=ByteToWord \ 16=ByteToDword \ 32=AbsJump \ 64=ShortJump \ 128=LongJump
End Type

Public Type DisAsmStruct
 Instruction_Prefix As Long
 Instruction As Long
 Reg1 As REGSTRUCT
 Reg2 As REGSTRUCT
 Reg_Reg As Long '1=from ptr
 Imm As IMMSTRUCT
 Instruction_Length As Long
End Type

'return buffer length
Declare Function DisAssemble Lib "disASM" (Data As Any, ByVal BaseAddress As Long, DisAsmString As Any, DisAsmS As Any, ByVal DisasmOpt As Long) As Long
```

Say you load file as binary to, the struct is initialized like so

```
Dim FDATA() as byte
Dim DisA As DisAsmStruct
```

The DLL Call would be

```
BufferLength = DisAssemble(FDATA(CNT), BaseAddress + CNT, ByVal Opcodes, DisA, 0)
```

The CNT value is a counter which gets incremented after the call based on how long the disassembled instruction was found to be

```
CNT = CNT + DisA.Instruction_Length
```

The other values in the DLL Function OpCodes is written string memory where the string of the human-readable asm code is printed.
Also DisA struct is filled out by that same DLL Function call.
The BufferLength is returned as a function return value I don't think I'd have any problems with that one it's used to trim the OpCodes string to proper string size later.

The OpCodes is declared like so.

```
Dim Opcodes     As String
Opcodes = String(128, 0)
```

Here is what I tried so far in C#

All my failure attempts

```
    //return buffer length
    [DllImport("disASM.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int DisAssemble(IntPtr Data, uint BaseAddress, IntPtr DisAsmString, IntPtr DisAsmS, uint DisasmOpt);

    [DllImport("disASM.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int DisAssemble(IntPtr Data, uint BaseAddress, string DisAsmString, DisAsmStruct DisAsmS, uint DisasmOpt);

    [DllImport("disASM.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern short DisAssemble(
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] [In] ref byte[] data, 
      uint BaseAddress,
      ref string DisAsmString,
      ref DisAsmStruct DisAsmS,
      uint DisasmOpt);

    [DllImport("disASM.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern short DisAssemble(
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] [In] ref byte[] data, 
      uint BaseAddress,
      ref string DisAsmString,
      ref DisAsmStruct DisAsmS,
      uint DisasmOpt);

    [DllImport("disASM.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern short DisAssemble(
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] [In] ref byte[] data, 
      uint BaseAddress,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]  ref string DisAsmString,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]ref DisAsmStruct DisAsmS,
      uint DisasmOpt);

//this looks like the best one
        [DllImport("disASM.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern int DisAssemble(IntPtr Data, uint BaseAddress, out string DisAsmString, out DisAsmStruct DisAsmS, uint DisasmOpt);
```

I cannot do like

```
    [DllImport("disASM.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern short DisAssemble(
      byte* data, 
      uint BaseAddress,
      string* DisAsmString,
      DisAsmStruct* DisAsmS,
      uint DisasmOpt);
```

because it would give error Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context

The closest attempt was this, it didn't work but I just feel it was good enough attempt as the pointer is exposed and incremented properly with CNT counter, just it's not getting passed due to some protection in .NET i don't know.

```
unsafe
{ 
    fixed(byte* test = &GLOBALDATA.FDATA[CNT])
    {
        IntPtr codeBuf = new IntPtr((void*)test);
        BufferLength = ModuleASM.DisAssemble(codeBuf, BaseAddress + CNT, out Opcodes, out DisA, 0);
    }
}
```

Online research said I do like this (doesn't work of course)

```
GCHandle fileDataPointered = GCHandle.Alloc(GLOBALDATA.FDATA[CNT], GCHandleType.Pinned);
BufferLength = ModuleASM.DisAssemble(fileDataPointered.AddrOfPinnedObject(), BaseAddress + CNT, ref Opcodes, ref DisA, 0);
//BufferLength = ModuleASM.DisAssemble(fileDataPointered.AddrOfPinnedObject(), BaseAddress + CNT, Opcodes, DisA, 0);
fileDataPointered.Free();
```

Online research example compiles fine but similar error to the unsafe code example

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in {$1}.exe
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

There was one tool that someone recommanded on google link I try called `P/Invoke Interop Assistant` which is suppose to generate a DLLImport based on loading a .DLL file into it.. I get a error from that as well that the .dll file is missing a assembly manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be having issues with the platform with 32 bit vs 64 bit.  VB6 is 32 bit only so DisAssemble.dll is a 32bit dll.

.Net supports both 32 bit and 64 bit and defaults to AnyCpu.  AnyCpu will run as 64 bit on a 64 bit operating system, which is most likely the case.

Try change the Target Platform to x86.

You cannot load a 32bit dll in a 64 bit process.  Also IntPtr is 8 bytes when running on a 64 bit CLR and 4 bytes when running on the 32 bit CLR.

Comment: Yes it indeed is AnyCpu and I am running 64-bit cpu, I'll see if this fixes the issue, okay it didn't solve the issue I did change from AnyCPU to x86, but it copied settings from AnyCpu as I didn't have x86 on the list there, but the issue is still the same if it did run in 32bit mode `Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

Comment: Fixed it :) I'll write my own solution in a bit, turned out to be using .NET `string` OpCodes doesn't work. had to use IntPtr OpCodes and problem went away and called successfully! woohoo!

Comment: Ok that error tells you that your dll is loading now.  Before that it wasn't loading at all.  Now you have an error in your calling code so you can work on that now.  Maybe others will help there.

Comment: BTW, I changed it back to AnyCPU and it still works fine.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't.  You cannot load a 32 bit dll in a 64 bit process, it's not possible.  Maybe your previous build is still in the bin folder and still running 32 bit.

Comment: Nope just cleaned all 4 projects (2x debugs/2x releases) and recompiled all 4 and AnyCPU one works 100% I guess this DLL has unique respects to both in some way odd, heh

Comment: Yes it works in all modes, just in Release mode I had to code in a `MessageBox.Show("a"); `to terminate  before running unfinished code. Why would a interpreted language like .NET not support loading 32bit dll's in a 64bit program after all it handles everything outside the program as far as i know. The signatures still haven't changed for DLLImports on those P/Invoke sites even though 64bit mode came out ages ago.. I think they made it all backwards compatible

Comment: Hey sorry for insulting your intelligence you were right all along x64 doesn't allow loading 32-bit dlls, I just used AnyCPU and x86 never tried x64 until today and it doesn't load disasm.dll `Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'disASM.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

Comment: The language isn't why it can't load 32 bit dlls.  Windows is.

A 64 bit Windows process cannot load 32 bit dlls, and a 32 bit windows process cannot load 64 bit dlls.  

The two layers are separated by WOW64 and it is what allows 32 bit programs to even run on a 64 bit windows OS.

I could go into it but basically, there are two windows api's, the 32 bit on, and the 64 bit one.  Windows API is static (Dynamic link libraries) so both can't be loaded at the same time.

Comment: Also.... .Net is not an interpreted language... That couldn't be more wrong.  .Net compiles to MSIL which is then JIT compiled to Machine Code (Assembly) when it is loaded.  Depending on where it is run, determines what it compiles to.  On a windows machine that's going to be x86 as either 32 bit or 64 bit code.

.Net is just as fast as C/C++ etc, what slows it down is the type safety (checking), the garbage collector, and other things that are abstracted.

Comment: cool stuff.. when I first started with .NET i never liked it because of the bulky .NET framework everyone had to install in order to us it which they fixed by now shipping it with every modern OS, other then that I never liked how it was so draggy and laggy the windows form code back when I used it on my Windows XP machine. I can't really tell the difference on my Windows 7 machine, unless you make a C/C++ Dialog and you could always tell the difference right away .NET feels like Adobe Flash Player compared to C/C++ Solid Forms heh. But all these scrafices are worth it imo,development speed =]

Comment: I always thought people should stick to making programming languages like VB6 and not stray away from that fast paced programming models, why always reinvent the wheel as they say.. I used to always rewrite a bunch of functions due to the lack of them, then I used to keep all the ones I needed in special folders to find them when I needed code banks, .NET solved this once again with their huge namespace of libraries. type safety is often not needed in .NET i'm glad they have unchecked mode because overflowing of integers should happen naturally they shouldn't try to fix it for regular numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100928/discussion-between-ryios-and-sspoke).

Answer (score 0):

Yay! I got it to call.

The problem was that .NET `string` is different from vb6 `String` I don't know the difference exactly.. but
vb6

```
Dim OpCodes As String
```

changing C#

```
string OpCodes;
```

to

```
IntPtr OpCodes;
```

completely fixed the problem, Yes it's not pretty but I have to take it out of the pointer back to string now, i'll work on that now.

At first I thought maybe I had to move all the variables into the unsafe scope.. I did that, no idea if it contributed to the fix.. but I think not that important to do, yes I tested the variables outside the unsafe scope still works fine!.

Full working code looks like this, okay it's not working for strings.. I'll keep at it, fixed that too

```
[DllImport("disASM.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int DisAssemble(IntPtr Data, uint BaseAddress, out IntPtr DisAsmString, out DisAsmStruct DisAsmS, uint DisasmOpt);


unsafe
{
    string Opcodes = new string((char)0, 128);
    IntPtr OpcodesTest;
    ModuleASM.DisAsmStruct DisAa = new ModuleASM.DisAsmStruct();
    fixed (byte* dataPtr = &GLOBALDATA.FDATA[CNT])
    {
        IntPtr dataBuf = new IntPtr((void*)dataPtr);
        BufferLength = ModuleASM.DisAssemble(dataBuf, BaseAddress + CNT, out OpcodesTest, out DisAa, 0);

        //Kinda like it.. need more characters like, PUSH ECX
        ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(OpcodesPtr.ToInt64())) //return "PUSH\0\0\0\0"

        byte testbbb = Marshal.ReadByte(OpcodesTest); //fail error
        string testa = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(OpcodesTest)); //fail error
        string testb = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(OpcodesTest); //blank return
        string testc = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(OpcodesTest); //fail error
        string testd = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(OpcodesTest)); //fail error
        string teste = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(OpcodesTest)); //fail error
        string testf = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(OpcodesTest); //fail error
    }
}
```